# Creating object with varying keys

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create object similar to this using loop, where I have separate array of country codes and another array of latitude and longitudes 
is there any way to achieve this in typescript,

```
var latlong={
            'us': {'latitude':39.528019315435685, 'longitude':-99.1444409552122},
            'fr': {'latitude':46.62065825554313, 'longitude':2.4521888685061306}
    }
```

Comment: you want to make 3 different arrays ?

Comment: how are the two arrays linked? is it through the array index or another common variable?

Comment: its object containing unique country code and its corresponding latitude and longitude, similar to object created here in echarts worldmap example [https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=scatter-world-population], but I am facing issues while creating same using loop, country code is not appearing as key

Comment: Can you give an example of the initial data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your arrays have **corresponding** index, then you can use this sample code,

```
let country = ['us','fr'];
let lat = ['39.528019315435685','46.62065825554313'];
let long = ['-99.1444409552122','2.4521888685061306'];

let latlong = {};

country.forEach((code,index)=>{
   latlong[code] = {};
   latlong[code]['latitude'] = lat[index];
   latlong[code]['longitude'] = long[index];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both arrays are correctly mapped through their indices, you could try :

```
coordinatesArray.forEach((coordinate, index)=>{
    latlong[countryArray[index]] = coordinate;
});
```

where coordinatesArray contains an array of latitude and longitude objects and countryArray contains the country string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's small example of way to create desired object.

[CodeSandbox-project](https://codesandbox.io/s/ovxjzm32ny)

Basically you iterate through other array and with index reference to your other array. with `obj[key]` you can create object with variables as keys.

And just to open a bit discussion about achieving this in `TypeScript`. `TypeScript` basically only extends existing `EcmaScript`-syntax with types so this would work in vanillaJS or in TypeScript as expected. Benefit you get in `TypeScript` is if you would have typed your variables.

eg.

```
const country: string[] = ['fr','en']
```

So now your IDE can show you that you expect `country`-variable only to contain strings.